# Logout from Facebook using Social Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, social-framework

I have used the **SLComposeViewController** for Facebook Integration in iOS6. It is working fine for posting . But my issue is I have a button called Logout in the app . When I click on it the user has to be logged out from the FaceBook . I have searched all the ways but failed . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can log the user out of their system Facebook account, nor can you programmatically revoke your app's ability to access the account.

Your best bet is to pop up an alert telling the user that to change their Facebook settings, go to the Settings app.